# What was Verne doing?

Tags: plot-explanation, back-to-the-future-part-3

I noticed this strange action done by Verne at the ending of Back to the Future III, which appears to be a little indecent. This scene appear in duration **01:50:40 to 01:50:45**

[image: Verne's action.]

Was this a mistake or there is some plot explanation behind this too?

Comment: Interesting question. The prevalent (and quite logical) theory seems to be that the kid is simply signaling that he has to go to the bathroom. He does have a rather pained expression in the full scene.

Comment: Looks like the brat wanted his closeup.

Comment: I agree, "out of character" he appears to be signalling the crew somehow.  Perhaps it's a pre-arranged cue for when the cameraman should begin closing in.  If you want it to be explained "in character," the simplest explanation would be that the boy is just playing with his hand.  Fidgeting pointlessly.  I don't think the gesture means anything relevant to the scene.

Comment: It has been explained online (i can find the link later) that he had to go pee and was afraid to ask

Comment: @fabriced I thought that was more of speculation

Comment: I always assumed he was signaling for Marty to come closer. If memory serves this is immediately before Doc hands Marty the gift wrapped picture.

Answer (score 4):

There was no plot explanation.  There is much speculation (and I highly doubt this is going to show up in an interview or in DVD commentary since it should have been spotted by the Continuity Editor) that the actor needed to go to the bathroom.  If you have kids in the 6-8 age range, which is approximately how old Dannel Evans was at the time, you know that kids are notorious for needing to go to the bathroom 10 minutes after being asked, as in when you're leaving for a lengthy car ride.  Considering the pained look on his face and that he's mouthing something to someone while looking like he's about to cry (you need to watch the entire clip to see what exactly is going on), I'd say he's in desperate need of a bathroom break.

BTW, this has been floating around the Internet for almost 10 years.  Most references find it amusing to call the kid "creepy", so that's just what stuck.